# Are there any rowhammer resistance phones?

Tags: security, hardware, ram

It's taken 31 years but someone [finally](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/10/using-rowhammer-bitflips-to-root-android-phones-is-now-a-thing/) get around to implementing rowhammer for the arm instruction set.

So are there any [ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) or MEU RAM chips available for phones or currently in use in any phones?

Comment: Now ECC has an issue; https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/11/potentially-disastrous-rowhammer-bitflips-can-bypass-ecc-protections/

Answer (score 6):

The list from the
*Drammer* app mentioned in your first link, shows some devices are **not** vulnerable, E.g, HTC Desire 510.( [Row hammer wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer#TRR) suggests that ECC overcomes TRR mentioned below the table)

[image]

Quoting from [Source](http://www.vusec.net/projects/drammer/)

> We encourage everybody to try our Drammer test app and help figuring out how widespread mobile Rowhammer is. We expect, for example, that devices equipped with LPDDR4 are less vulnerable. This is because the LPDDR4 standard includes optional hardware support for the so-called target row refresh mitigation.
>
> I have a phone with LPDDR4 memory. Am I safe against Drammer attacks?
>
> Again, we don’t know. Chances are that your DRAM comes with the Target Row Refresh (TRR) mitigation, which makes it harder – but still not impossible, in theory – to induce bit flips. Moreover, TRR for LPDDR4 is optional, so your DRAM manufacturer may have decided to drop this technique and leave you vulnerable.

I doubt if you get that specific *confirmation* of implementation as you can see from [How to know whether a RAM module is vulnerable to rowhammer before buying?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/96488/99059) a question on Security SE

From another question on [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83409/what-are-the-security-implications-of-row-hammer-attack), answers imply ECC is not necessarily a protection against the rowhammer vulnerability

> Using ECC, whilst not a guarantee of security, might lower the probability of successful exploitation.

**Edit:** Based on the [paper submitted](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2978406&CFID=857869249&CFTOKEN=58573655) on 26 Oct 16 by the authors in the annual CCS 2016 , which is quite beyond my understanding, my conclusions are :

1. There are many countermeasures and ECC is one of them ( clearly my understanding that ECC was the sole reason is wrong as also pointed out by OP in comments
2. Following devices were shown to be **not vulnerable** in the tests and as mentioned in the conclusion of paper x86 devices are not

[image]

Comment: There is plenty of RAM that is made well enough to resist for longer so just because a RAM chip is not susceptible dose not mean that it will stay that way or that it has ECC...

Comment: + with an N=1 it's not saying much.

Comment: With N = 1, I assume you mean statistically ; I am not sure what N should be to make it a reliable indicator as the same device model can have RAM from different production batches with different performance ( within acceptable parameters)?