# What is this "Rowhammer" vulnerability in news said to affect millions of devices? Is my device affected?

Tags: security

Rowhammer vulnerability is [making news](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/10/using-rowhammer-bitflips-to-root-android-phones-is-now-a-thing/) and blogs/ websites claiming [**millions of Android devices could be affected?**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3868766/The-Rowhammer-bug-threatens-millions-Android-devices-Experts-reveal-bit-flip-flaw-attacks-memory-chips.html)

- What is it? How does it work?
- How do I test if my device is affected?

While this is is a self answered question, updates / additional inputs are welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl:dr;** Rowhammer is a hardware vulnerability ( memory based ) that can **potentially root your Android device and access data**. A malicious app with **zero permissions** could be used to aid this

---

> ## What is it? How does it work?

## What is Row hammer?

- It is a vulnerability . This vulnerability was previously known ( see [Project Zero [Google]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Zero_%28Google%29)) in the context of **PCs / Linux** (see [this](http://news.softpedia.com/news/rowhammer-attack-can-now-root-android-devices-509585.shtml))  and [Row hammer wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer#TRR) covers the technical aspects and mitigation
- Rowhammer is a hardware bug that allows *attackers to manipulate data in memory* without accessing it.
- [What is DRAM Rowhammer Attack?](http://thehackernews.com/2016/10/root-android-phone-exploit.html)

  - The Rowhammer attack involves executing a malicious application that repeatedly accesses the same "row" of transistors on a memory chip in a tiny fraction of a second in a process called "Hammering."
  - As a result, hammering a memory region can disturb neighboring row, causing the row to leak electricity into the next row which eventually causes a bit to flip. And since bits encode data, this small change modifies that data, creating a way to gain control over the device.

    - In short, Rowhammer is an issue with new generation DRAM chips in which repeatedly accessing a row of memory can cause "bit flipping" in an adjacent row that could allow anyone to change the value of contents stored in the memory.
    - [Pictorial explanation from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer#TRR)

[image]

## OK thanks ..what about Android?

- Rowhammer vulnerability for mobile devices has been reported first by [vusec](https://www.vusec.net/projects/drammer/)
- This vulnerability has been marked as *critical* by Google and assigned [CVE-2016-6728](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-6728) by Google and Google is expected to release a patch in November. Due to the nature of  attack  – exploiting a hardware vulnerability – implementing  comprehensive patch is not easy according to vusec
- Rowhammer RAM attack for rooting Android devices, and can even be combined with existing Android vulnerabilities such as [Bandroid](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/4dxwz4/the_bandroid_vulnerability/) and [Stagefright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagefright_%28bug%29). This means that an **app having no permissions can potentially root Android device** (see vusec paper, which also has videos demonstrating this )

> ## How do I test if my device is affected?

- An android app **Drammer** (Deterministic RowhAMMER) has been developed by vusec and can be [side loaded](https://www.vusec.net/projects/drammer/). (**See edit** )
- The app does not give you a nice popup that tells you whether you are vulnerable or not. You can easily spot induced bit flips by glancing over the output and looking for the obvious keyword `FLIP`. Sample output from my device below

[image]

- *Your phone might still be vulnerable, even if the app detected zero flips!* Because of current implementation of app and it may not have fully tested  memory , which implies results may not be conclusive
- [Hammertime Simuator](https://github.com/vusec/hammertime) is also available on GitHub

**Vusec test results**

- *Not every phone is susceptible for the Rowhammer bug*.   27 devices and were able to flip bits on 18 of them. In the table below, you can find statistics on devices that were tested so far.

[image]

- **Is there an Android phone that is *not vulnerable?*** ( See edit 2 below)

I don't know and there has been no report on internet by researchers or OEM's claiming that they are not vulnerable. Also see this related question [Are there any rowhammer resistance phones?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160699/131553)

**Edit 1** I got a warning from Google against this *Drammer* app though I sideloaded from official vusec link

[image]

**Edit 2:** Based on the [paper submitted](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2978406&CFID=857869249&CFTOKEN=58573655) on 26 Oct 16 by the authors in the annual CCS 2016 , which is quite beyond my understanding, my conclusions are :

1. There are many countermeasures both software and hardware
2. Following devices were shown to be **not vulnerable** in the tests and as mentioned in the conclusion of paper x86 devices )

[image]